# Ngrx effects return successAction before completing the backend

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In an optimistic workflow, I'd like to fire the success action before the backend fetchs data:

something like this

```
  @Effect()
  save$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(myActions.SAVE)
    .map((action: myActions.SaveAction) => action.payload)
    .// dispatch success here ?
    .switchMap((foo) => {
      return this.myService
        .updateFoo(foo)
        .catch(error => Observable.of(new myActions.SaveFailAction(error)));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.do(new myActions.SomeSuccessAction)`

or, if you'll go and use pipeable operators (with rxjs 5.5+) then `do` is renamed to `tap`.

just out of curiousity...why would you want to do something like that?

instead of firing extra action, wouldn't you be better off having `myActions.SaveActionWithEarlySuccessAction` (instead of myAction.SaveAction) and then this effect and whatever else reacts to that particular one?

Answer (score 0):

Since `SAVE` is already synchronous, you don't need a `SaveSuccess` action. You can just do anything you want to do for `SaveSuccess` for `Save` instead and otherwise keep what you have the same.

```
switchMap(foo => this.myService.updateFoo(foo).pipe(
  map(() => new MyActions.NullAction()),
  catchError(error => of(new MyActions.SaveFailAction(error)),
));
```

You still have to return an action on success to prevent an endless loop, but it doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: @RachidOussanaa Does this help? Is there anything I can do to improve my answer?